# Jquery wrong value captured for quantity text value when I click on + or - button

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, shopping-cart

The wrong value is being captured for the quantity text value when I click on `+` or `-` cart quantity adjustment button. For example, the initial quantity value from server side is 4.

When I click the plus the UI shows up as 5, but in `console.log` it reads the value as outdated 4.

If I try another way to capture keyup change click, it only can read the value when user actually go to interact with the textbox.

Wonder how to capture correct final value after the button click...

```js
$(document).on('click', '.qty-control', function(event) {
  var cartid = $(this).attr("data-cartid");
  var qty = $('#qty_' + cartid).val();
  console.log(qty);
});

$(document).on('keyup change click', '.itemqty', function(event) {
  alert('trigger');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="qty-control left" data-click="decrease-qty" data-target="#qty_25" data-cartid="25">
  <i class="fa fa-minus">-</i>
</a>
<input type="number" name="qty" value="4" class="form-control itemqty" id="qty_25" min="0" placeholder="Qty">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="qty-control right" data-click="increase-qty" data-target="#qty_25" data-cartid="25">
  <i class="fa fa-plus">+</i>
</a>
```

Comment: The value is never changed in your example, and the console shows the right one. I'm confused what the issue is

Comment: Think I just found the answer. The template that I'm using is using data-target="# "  to reference to the id (which is quantity input).   I believe the template itself added got build in jquery event making the value increment when i click the + sign. But it won't show up the right value when I want to retrieve. So I just remove data-target and use the normal way now.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the code that does the quantity change:

```js
var qtyChange = {'increase-qty': 1, 'decrease-qty': -1};
$(document).on('click', '.qty-control', function(event) {
  var cartid = $(this).attr("data-cartid");
  var qty = parseInt($('#qty_' + cartid).val()) + qtyChange[$(this).data('click')];
  console.log(qty);
  $('#qty_' + cartid).val(qty);
});

$(document).on('keyup change click', '.itemqty', function(event) {
  alert('trigger');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="qty-control left" data-click="decrease-qty" data-target="#qty_25" data-cartid="25">
  <i class="fa fa-minus">-</i>
</a>
<input type="number" name="qty" value="4" class="form-control itemqty" id="qty_25" min="0" placeholder="Qty">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="qty-control right" data-click="increase-qty" data-target="#qty_25" data-cartid="25">
  <i class="fa fa-plus">+</i>
</a>
```